# Get zip from web url automatically and unzip it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, zip, scheduled-tasks

I need to go to this url:
http://autospace.by/download/prices.zip

And unzip this file to my rails app, but i must to do it on every 2.00pm every day, main trouble is that on other url's file in archive is name-changing every day, so i must unzip file, name ending of which is ,and do some manipulations with it?

my code now:

```
require 'net/http'
    Net::HTTP.start("autospace.by") do |http|
        resp = http.get("/download/prices.zip")
        open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads_prices', "autospace.zip"), "wb") do |file|
            file.write(resp.body)
        end
    end
```

**So:** how can i unzip file on this url, and send this file name as param to method mymethod(filename)? And also give advice how to do this every day automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly use linux zip command `system "cd #{Rails.root}/#{zip_path}; zip -qr #{zip_file_name}.zip #{zip_file_name};`

or use ruby [zip](https://github.com/javanthropus/archive-zip) gems

```
  gem 'archive-zip'  # Use require_gem for rubygems versions older than 0.9.0.
  require 'archive/zip'

  # Add a_directory and its contents to example1.zip.
  Archive::Zip.archive('example1.zip', 'a_directory')
```

if you want excute this every day, just run this script in crontab, for example

```
   `*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/ruby  /local/myuser/rubyscript/ftpscript.rb >> /local/myuser/rubyscript/ftplog.txt`
```

Comment: gem 'archive-zip'  write this according to my code, how to join it?

Comment: execute `gem "archive-zip" at your teminate, and add `require 'archive/zip'` in your scripts

Comment: how then could i get name of file? if it could be 13-12name, 14-12name etc... i must send it;s name to method

Comment: First you should download the zip , give it a local file name by youself,and then unzip it

Comment: if i now how to code it in ruby... i didn't ask here! give example!

Comment: what's the rule of filename in the url, like 13-12name 14-12name, it depends on time changing  ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21107/discussion-between-richie-min-and-pavelby)

Comment: are there any rails "cron-php-like" schedulers?